# Bug Eclipse (Spring Tools Suite) cannot return a void result - cannot cast to int

Tags: spring, eclipse, casting

I have a bug eclipse. I cannot return a void result. even though other function (same with this function) can return a void result to int. and I try run in other PC with Spring tools suite, have a suggestion for cast to int. How to fix this bug for eclipse. Thank you.

[Spring Tools Suite error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9v0Qy.png)

Regards,
Bobby

Comment: Show us the code as text, not an image where the error message is hiding the code in error.

Comment: @Transactional
 public int update(KasusEntity user) {
  return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(user);
 }

Comment: in DAOImpl.java